# Create radio buttons using jquery - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery

This might be easy but I'm having difficulties doing it. I've got 3 radio buttons in my HTML and now I 'm looking to create them dynamically.

This is the standard radio button I'm having (I'm using bootstrap)

```
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="radio" class="locakable" name="radioGroup" value="First Radio Button" required></span>
     <input class="form-control locakableR" value="First Radio Button" readonly>
</div>
```

This is how I tried to create them. But the radio buttons are not getting populated.

```
<div id="serviceRadios"></div>

$.getJSON('php/service.php',function(dta){
      $.each(dta,function(index,item){
        var servicetypeRadios = $('<div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" class="locakable" value="'+item.serviceType_id+'" required/></span>
          <input class="form-control locakableR" value="'+item.service+'" readonly>
        </div><br />;');
      });

      $('#serviceRadios').html(servicetypeRadios);
      //servicetypeRadios.appendTo('#serviceRadios');
    });
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The radio buttons are not getting populated.

Comment: Ah I see, you need string concatenation `value="' + item.service + '"`.

Comment: You don't have any script tags wrapping your javascript code. Is this normal ?

Comment: @DOCASAREL: +1 Yep, I missed that but something is still worng. The radio buttons are now being populated. I'll do your suggestion in my post now so the others will not bring that up. Thanks

Comment: you say they are getting populated, what is the problem now

Comment: @AlbanPommeret: sure the script tags are there. I've only included the code which is relevant to my question. Thanks.

Comment: @DOCASAREL Apologies. The radio buttons are noT being populated

Comment: Haha, ok, look at Andrew Carl, he is up to something do you not get output in the console an error

Comment: consol: servicetypeRadios is not defined

Comment: @DOCASAREL: I tried defining `var servicetypeRadios = '';` just before `$.getJSON(` But now I get only the first radio button .

Comment: @DOCASAREL Yep... I got it... finally added a `+=` here `servicetypeRadios += '<div class="input-group">'+`. It's working now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a little bit. Please try this

```
$.getJSON('php/service.php',function(dta){
    var servicetypeRadios = '';
    $.each(dta,function(index,item){
        servicetypeRadios += '<div class="input-group">'+
                                    '<span class="input-group-addon"><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" class="locakable" value="'+item.serviceType_id+'" required/></span>'+
                                    '<input class="form-control locakableR" value="'+item.service+'" readonly>'+
                                '</div><br />';
    });
    $('#serviceRadios').html(servicetypeRadios);
      //servicetypeRadios.appendTo('#serviceRadios');
});
```

Comment: consol: servicetypeRadios is not defined. Might have to define `var servicetypeRadios = '';` just before `$.getJSON(` and add `+=` here `servicetypeRadios += '<div class="input-group">'+`

Comment: Yep... just like that. that's it!

Comment: I earned you 15... ;) ha?

Comment: I can only get you +5.:)(+1 for you question) How would I pass on your 10??

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#serviceRadios').html(servicetypeRadios);
```

You can't get  variable `**servicetypeRadios**` because it is a local variable.
You may need to declare servicetypeRadios correctly .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/evsyh7so/1/)

I am taking the provided html as a Template that repeats again against the set of values in the array;

let the array get the values from async call as below

```
  var listofvalues = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; // your values from ajax
```

then the jquery you can use as

```
    $(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        var $template = "<div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon'><input type='radio' class='locakable' name='radioGroup' value='{{radiovalue}}' required></span><input class='form-control locakableR' value='{{radiotext}}' readonly></div><br/>";
        var listofvalues = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; // your values from ajax
       //  $('.input-group').html('');  // cleaning the div to populate again
        $.each(listofvalues, function (index, value) {

            $('#serviceRadios').append($template.replace('{{radiovalue}}', value).replace('{{radiotext}}', value))
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps ...

Comment: Thanks that's nice... works perfectly. But my question included some extra html.